# What do the "%s", "%d" etc. mean in Delphi programming?

Tags: delphi

Everytime I look at some of the more expert code online I see things like `%s` and `%d` in some strings, especially in dialogs, but I have no idea what they are. I have googled the terms and I can't seem to find the answer and whether it is Delphi-bound or something common to every programming language.

I saw a post relating to C saying that it is used to "convert variables at runtime", how many arguments can we specify in a single string if this is the case?

Example usage:

```
ShowMessageFmt('Day %d = %s',[i,Days[i]]);
```

found at [Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Arrays).

Comment: Format specifiers are [`described here`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.Format#Format_Strings).

Comment: These specifiers were originally created for the C language `printf` formatting and adapted later by other languages, such as in Delphi. Thus, you'll find various hits with Google.

Comment: The page you link to says "The ShowMessageFmt routine displays our data - click on it to learn more." Didn't you click?

Comment: What language uses backslashes, @Mg30rg?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Those are format strings, similar to those used in C `printf()`. They're also used by the Delphi `Format` function, which again is similar to `printf()` in C.

`%d` represents an integer. It will be replaced by the content of the variable `i` that is provided in the array that follows it.

`%s` represents a string. It will be replaced by the content of `Days[i]` that is passed in the array that follows it.

You can find more information in the Delphi documentation for [`SysUtils.Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.Format), specifically in the sub-section regarding [`Format Strings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.Format#Format_Strings).

Answer (score 12):

These are format strings that are passed to the `Format` function. Read all about it in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format#Format_Strings).

Each placeholder in your format string is replaced by a value from the arguments open array. So, `%d` is replaced with the value of `i`, and `%s` is replaced with the value of `Days[i]`.

The format string placeholders specify the data type and formatting information. So, `%d` is used to display an integer value in decimal representation, and `%s` is used to indicate a string.